# For a given period, getting the smallest list of dates, using jokers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I use Elasticsearch where I have one index per day, and I want my Ruby on Rails application to query documents in a given period by specifying the smallest and most precise list of indices.

I can't find the code to get that list of indices. Let me explain it:

Consider a date formatted in `YYYY-MM-DD`.
You can use the joker `*` at the end of the date string. E.g. `2016-07-2*` describes all the dates from `2016-07-20` to `2016-07-29`.

Now, consider a period represented by a start date and an end date.

The code must return the smallest possible array of dates representing the period.

Let's use an example. For the following period:

- start date: `2014-11-29`
- end date: `2016-10-13`

The code must return an array containing the following strings:

- `2014-11-29`
- `2014-11-30`
- `2014-12-*`
- `2015-*`
- `2016-0*`
- `2016-10-0*`
- `2016-10-10`
- `2016-10-11`
- `2016-10-12`
- `2016-10-13`

It's better (but I'll still take a unoptimized code rather than nothing) if:

- The code returns the most precise list of dates (i.e. doesn't return dates with a joker that describes a period starting before the start date, or ending after the end date)
- The code returns the smallest list possible (i.e. `["2016-09-*"]` is better than `["2016-09-0*", "2016-09-1*", "2016-09-2*", "2016-09-30"]`

Any idea?

Comment: Did you start any implementation? It's a better idea share your code and ask for help with it instead of write a problem and ask for a solution...

Comment: Not really, I'm stuck at the beginning. Fortunately Rails has all the methods needed for manipulating dates (e.g. Date.parse, <date>.beginning_of_month, <date> + 1) but I have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after more thinking and the help of a coworker, I may have a solution. Probably not totally optimized, but still...

```
def get_indices_from_period(start_date_str, end_date_str)
  dates = {}
  dates_strings = []
  start_date = Date.parse(start_date_str)
  end_date = Date.parse(end_date_str)

  # Create a hash with, for each year and each month of the period: {:YYYY => {:MMMM => [DD1, DD2, DD3...]}}
  (start_date..end_date).collect do |date|
    year, month, day = date.year, date.month, date.day
    dates[year] ||= {}
    dates[year][month] ||= []
    dates[year][month] << day
  end

  dates.each do |year, days_in_year|
    start_of_year = Date.new(year, 1, 1)
    max_number_of_days_in_year = (start_of_year.end_of_year - start_of_year).to_i + 1
    number_of_days_in_year = days_in_year.collect{|month, days_in_month| days_in_month}.flatten.size

    if max_number_of_days_in_year == number_of_days_in_year
      # Return index formatted as YYYY-* if full year
      dates_strings << "#{year}-*"

    else
      days_in_year.each do |month, days_in_month|
        formatted_month = format('%02d', month)
        if Time.days_in_month(month, year) == days_in_month.size
          # Return index formatted as YYYY-MM-* if full month
          dates_strings << "#{year}-#{formatted_month}-*"

        else
          decades_in_month = {}
          days_in_month.each do |day|
            decade = day / 10
            decades_in_month[decade] ||= []
            decades_in_month[decade] << day
          end

          decades_in_month.each do |decade, days_in_decade|
            if (decade == 0 && days_in_decade.size == 9) ||
              ((decade == 1 || decade == 2) && days_in_decade.size == 10)
              # Return index formatted as YYYY-MM-D* if full decade
              dates_strings << "#{year}-#{formatted_month}-#{decade}*"

            else
              # Return index formatted as YYYY-MM-DD
              dates_strings += days_in_decade.collect{|day| "#{year}-#{formatted_month}-#{format('%02d', day)}"}
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  return dates_strings
end
```

Test call:

`get_indices_from_period('2014-11-29', '2016-10-13')`

`=> ["2014-11-29", "2014-11-30", "2014-12-*", "2015-*", "2016-01-*", "2016-02-*", "2016-03-*", "2016-04-*", "2016-05-*", "2016-06-*", "2016-07-*", "2016-08-*", "2016-09-*", "2016-10-0*", "2016-10-10", "2016-10-11", "2016-10-12", "2016-10-13"]`